# ios6 Safari bug on orientation change when <input> has placeholder text

Tags: html, ios6, placeholder, orientation-changes

I have a bug on mobile safari iOS6 only where the layout is shifted to the left on orientation change - from portrait to landscape and back.

The bug only exists if there is content in the placeholder attribute, if you remove the content of the placeholder attribute there is no bug on orientation change. I have set up a demo at http://beta.9eggs.com/ios6.html where you can toggle the content of the placeholder of an input and add remove the bug.

I have seen solutions to fix the layout problems but would like to understand the reasons why placeholder causes the problem and fix that - not the containing layout.

Comment: Care to share the solutions you have found to fix this? I've just discovered this issue myself but can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: I've been tackling the same issue. It's a pain!

Answer (score 13):

Try to set `overflow: hidden;` on `input`'s parent element, it worked for me.

Comment: Applied this to the <form> and fixed the problem!

Comment: Found this after hours of futzing around! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Words cannot express how ANNOYING this was to find, how long it took to pinpoint the problem to the placeholder attribute, and how difficult it was to find this specific answer online.  Applying `style="overflow:hidden;"` to the `<form>` containing the `<input>` element fixed it for me.

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes. Simple solution to a very frustrating bug.

Answer (score 2):

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515058/ios6-safari-orientation-change-bug?rq=1) lead me to a solution that works for me. It boils down to this general purpose kludge:

```
if ( /iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
     !/Opera Mini/.test(navigator.userAgent) )
{
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(e){
    /*
      // Method A:
      var s = document.documentElement.style;
      s.display = 'none';
      setTimeout(function(){ s.display = 'block'; }, 0);
    */
      // Method B:
      var d = document.documentElement;
      setTimeout(function(d){ d.className = d.className; }, 0);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of `getElementsByTagName` you can use `document.documentElement`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.documentElement

Comment: Thanks! I updated the example, and fixed a minor typo in there as well. :)

Comment: This solution is good, but makes short "flash". You can force repaint simpler:

`if ( /iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
     !/Opera Mini/.test(navigator.userAgent) )
{
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(e){
      var c = document.documentElement;
      setTimeout(function(){ c.className = c.className; }, 0);
    });
}`