# Safari IOS6 "position: fixed" with opened keyboard and changed orientation

Tags: safari, ios6

I have top menu in Ipad with `position: fixed` and `width: 100%` in my site, which is displayed fine, when *keyboard is shown and orientation is changed* (f.e., from Landscape to Portrait) in Safari IOS5, but **not** in IOS6.

In IOS6 after this actions top menu becomes shifted to right at **128px**. I found some very close problem, related exactly to 128px in StackOverflow [iOS6 Safari orientation change bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515058/ios6-safari-orientation-change-bug), but solution was not applicable to my case.

So, investigating a little, I changed in javascript event "orientationchange" the CSS property of top menu `position:fixed` to `position:relative`.

And that helped, my top menu redrew correctly. But, as I needed exactly `position:fixed` later for my site, I added `setTimeout()` method, which returned CSS `position` back to value `fixed`.

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function(e){
        $('#framecontentTop').css('position', 'relative');
        setTimeout(function(e){
             $('#framecontentTop').css('position', 'fixed');
        }, 500)
});
```

I think, it is the temporary solution. Does somebody know real root cause of a problem, or it is IOS6 bug?